# Xamarin MSAL NuGet error - Version conflict detected for Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017, nuget, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to add the MSAL NuGet package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client to a Xamarin forms project but keep getting the following error:

```
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 
'MobileApp.Android'.                
Error   NU1107  Version conflict detected for 
Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat. Install/reference 
Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 27.0.2.1 directly to project 
MobileApp.Android to resolve this issue. 
MobileApp.Android -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter 
27.0.2.1 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette 27.0.2.1 -> 
Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 27.0.2.1) 
MobileApp.Android -> Microsoft.Identity.Client 2.2.0-preview -> 
Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs 27.0.2 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 
(= 27.0.2).
```

I've tried clearing the NuGet cache from Visual Studio 2017 -> Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager, and also manually clearing the cache by deleting the contents of the following folders:

```
%userprofile%\.nuget\packages
%localappdata%\NuGet\v3-cache
%temp%\NuGetScratch
%localappdata%\NuGet\plugins-cache
```

I've also tried creating a new blank project and just adding the NuGet package but continue to receive the same error. NuGet seems to working OK for other types of projects.

Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: In your android project, have you tried to update the following package: Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, before to install MSAL package ?

Comment: I already have the latest stable version. I had tried updating all the Xamarin.Android packages to the latest prerelease versions (as MSAL is also prerelease), but I continued to receive errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Xamarin MSAL NuGet error - Version conflict detected for Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat

This is nuget package version conflict issue.

**To resolve this issue**, you should install the package **`Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs 27.0.2.1`** **at first**, then install the package **`Microsoft.Identity.Client`**.

The reason for this issue:

Since you have already installed the package `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter 
27.0.2.1` in your project, which have a indirect dependence `Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 27.0.2.1)`. When you install the package `Microsoft.Identity.Client` to the project, which also have a indirect dependence `Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 27.0.2)`. You could notice that the versions are different, a project cannot reference the same reference different version, which cause the version conflict.

To resolve this issue, we need to unify the references of these two different versions. Check the Dependencies of the package `Microsoft.Identity.Client 2.2.0-preview`, this package have a dependency `Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs (>= 27.0.2)` and the dependency `Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs (>= 27.0.2)` also have a dependency `Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 27.0.2)`. So to resolve this issue, we just need to install the dependency `Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs (>= 27.0.2.1)` at first, which have the dependency is `Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 27.0.2.1)`:

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Worked first time. Thanks.